# Year dropdown in jsf

Tags: jsp, jsf, richfaces

How can I use `<rich:calendar>` to only display year.
I want year dropdown in jsf How can I achieve it.Please guide

I tried

```
<rich:calendar value="#{existingPolicyRecord.dateOfApp}" datePattern="yyyy" ></rich:calendar>
```

But unable to get year dropdown.Is there any other component for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This isn't officially supported and I guess it would be better to do that with a normal dropdown selectBox** because you only have a list of values (years).

Nevertheless there is a [way](http://relation.to/12480.lace) to get the calendar to show only month and year:

create a style class to hide the "days":

> ```
> <style type="text/css">
>         .special tr[id]{
>                 display:none; 
>         }
> </style>
> ```

disable footer, days and weeks and apply style class to your calendar:

```
    <rich:calendar value="#{calendarBean.selectedDate}" popup="false" 
     showWeeksBar="false" showWeekDaysBar="false" showFooter="true" styleClass="special"/>
```

It will look like this:
[image] [image]